# How to create generic partial view to render a photo from flickr

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm creation a personal flickr page where i want so show my flickr photos, favs, etc..

I'm doing this using asp.net mvc 3 technology. This small project is actually my first real project i'm trying to complete for myself. To see if I get the basics of MVC or not.

So I've set up a small framework to be able to authenticate with Flickr and get the JSON response for my requests. (containing data for images)

I render these images as a list. Here's the view for that:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="slides">
        @Html.Partial("PhotoList", Model)
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a strongly typed view using the following type:

```
    public class FlickrPhotoCollection
    {
       public string size { get; set; }
       public List<FlickrPhoto> photo { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, it contains a List with photo objects and a size. The size attribute is to set the size of the image. ("t" = thumbnail, "m" = medium,....)

Two other partial views are used next:

PhotoList:

```
  @model FlickrPhotoCollection               
  @ViewBag.Size = @Model.size;

  @foreach (FlickrPhoto p in Model.photo)
  {
      <li>                   
        @Html.Partial("Photo", p)          
      </li>
   }
```

Photo:

```
@model FlickrPhoto

<img src="@(Model.display()" name="modal" class="photo" ref="@Model.owner" flickrId="@Model.id" />
```

The display method of FlickrPhoto will return the path to the actual image depending on the demanded size.

```
private string display(string size)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(size))
        {
            size = "_" + size;
        }
        return String.Format("http://farm{0}.static.flickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}{4}.jpg", farm, server, id, secret, size);
    }
```

As you can see, this method needs a size parameter and i'm not passing the size parameter in the view.

My question: What should i change in my code so i can pass the size parameter properly?

The result should be that i can set the size parameter in the controller and my view will render different sized images depending on this parameter.

Here's how i want my controller to look like:

```
 public ActionResult PhotoViewer()
    {
        FlickrMethods flickrmethods = new FlickrMethods();
        FlickrPhotoCollection photocollection = flickrmethods.getPublicPhotos("57820970@N06", "1");
        photocollection.size = "b";
        return View(photocollection);
    }
```

I repeat my question again: How can i pass the size "b" to the display method of the FlickrPhoto class that is used in my partial view 'Photo'?

I hope i made it clear enough to understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to put the `size` property in the `FlickrPhoto` class and set it accordingly in your load method. Then in your Photo view you can
replace this:

```
<img src="@(Model.display()" name="modal" class="photo" ref="@Model.owner" flickrId="@Model.id" />
```

With this:

```
<img src="@(Model.display(Model.size))" name="modal" class="photo" ref="@Model.owner" flickrId="@Model.id" />
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at my question. I first tried that, but did not know where and how to set the size property in the flickrphoto class. Can you show me how i can set that property? My current FlickrPhoto implementation is just a straight copy of the json response i get from flickr.

Comment: Here's how i did it: photocollection.size = "b"; will now loop through every flickrphoto in the collection and change it's size property too.  Is this the correct way to do this? It works, but i'm not sure if the performance will stay the same with larger collections?

Comment: Well that's a *way* to do it. You're best off setting it when you actually load up the photo and populate the other information.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "load up the photo"? I have a json string containing the photo objects. Then i parse this json into a List<FlickrPhoto>. Where can i set that size property? I hope i don't ask to much, it may look simple, but i can't find it out myself :(

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise you were parsing the photo objects directly from json. I thought you were loading them from a database and setting the properties yourself. If the size property is always the same why don't you just give it a default value in the class? just have the member declaration like `public string size = "b";` Otherwise if it's not always the same, the loop is probably your best bet in this scenario.

Comment: It's mostly the same size i need, so you're right with the default value. I can use the default value in most scenarios and use the loop for alternative uses. I still don't feel so good doing something like this, but i guess you're right and it's the only way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Ah okay no problems :). If you're changing some you could just use some LINQ instead of a loop to make it cleaner :)

Comment: Did you following any tutorial on how to integrate Flickr with MVC? I want to do this, but have no idea what so ever how to begin :(